# How can I dynamically disable a text box using Knockout's observables?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, knockout-validation, knockout-mvc

I'm implementing register form and when I click on submit button, I want to disable textbox using Knockout.

I have tried the following:

```
var viewModel = {
    Textboxcontrol: ko.observable(true), // by default textbox is enable to edit
    Register: {
        Init: function () {
        Textboxcontrol= false; // Updating the value to false 
                               // so Textbox should be disabled.
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

On UI I wrote as follows

```
<input  data-bind="value: Name, enable: Textboxcontrol" 
        type="text" autocomplete="off" />
```

But the problem is if I change the value to `Textboxcontrol= false;` also its taking the value as `True` only.. and textboxes are not disabling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Textboxcontrol is an observable, you must change its value by calling it as a function. Plus, you must use `this` to access the Textboxcontrol property inside your "Init" function :

```
var viewModel = {
  Name: ko.observable(''),
  Textboxcontrol: ko.observable(true),
  Register: {
    Init: function () {
      this.Textboxcontrol(false);
    }
  }
};
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. When I apply this.Textboxcontrol(false) am getting script issue that "Object doesn't support property or method 'Textboxcontrol'. What might be the issue? any idea? Thanks

Comment: Here is a fiddle with the exact same solution as I suggested : http://jsfiddle.net/HbfhB/ . If your code doesn't work, there is probably something else to fix (could you post it somewhere ?)

Comment: I'm sure there is a small mistake am doing in js file.. here is the js file and appreciated for the help. http://jsfiddle.net/deepakreview/9bkMS/1/

Comment: @user2010114 In your success function when you try to set the `EnabletxtControl` value, it is possible that `this` isn't your `viewModel` - try using `viewModel.EnabletxtControl(false)`

Comment: Can you edit your fiddle to make it quickly testable ? There is no easy way to try disabling the textbox.